# Javascript drawImage and newImage() change file format

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, merge, drawimage

Can i change image format? i want save as jpg, not png.

```
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_final");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img1 = loadImage(imageData, main);
        var img2 = loadImage('imagens/mask.png', main);

        var imagesLoaded = 0;
        function main() {
            imagesLoaded += 1;

            if(imagesLoaded == 2) {
                ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
                //ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
                ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 400);
            }
        }

        function loadImage(src, onload) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = onload;
            img.src = src;
            return img;
        }
```

After display using img.src i want change file format to (jpeg) and not (png)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the canvas to a Data URI using [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL). Depending on your requirement, you could have an export button that would request the following:

```
ctx.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

Comment: Mime type should be "image/jpeg" your will return a png  Use this to check browser for compliance http://kangax.github.io/jstests/toDataUrl_mime_type_test/ You forgot to add image quality setting which is very important for "jpeg". There are also browser specific formats eg Chrome toDataURL("image/webp",quality)

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the typo in the MIME. It was just an example as it's not totally clear what the requirement is.